# What is the source of this Hadith from Imam Sadeq (a.s.) ? "looking at non-Mahram is a poison arrow from Satan's arrows"

Tags: source-identification, shiism, shaitan, non-mahram, imam-sadiq

previously, I had heard a tradition from Imam Sadeq(Sadiq) (a.s.) regarding looking at non-mahrams that:

> «النّظرة سهمٌ من سهام إبلیس مسمومٌ من ترکها للّه لا لغیره أعقبه
>   اللّه إیماناً یجد طعمه»
>
> Looking (at non-mahrams) is a poison arrow from Satan's arrows,
>   whoever leaves it for the sake of Allah not for the sake of others
>   (except him), Allah will give him a faith (Iman) that he tastes its
>   flavor.

I wonder what is its reference?

Answer (score 6):

Sheikh Hor Ameli, Mohammad bin Hasan, Vasael Al Shia, V20, pg190, AlalBait institute, Qom, First Edition, 1409(lunar)